# Apache James: Get notify once delivery or bounce

Tags: java, james

I have a project which require the updates from mail server, I intend to use Apache James.

The updates required are:

1. When the mail sent: I need the time when it is sent
2. When the mail bounced: I need the bounced time, reason and is it soft bounce or hard bounce.

I know that James have hook mechanism and Mailet (looks like this only for process before send). I try to google around and also look at the API, but still not figure out the entry point.

Anyone have experience in this area please help me!

Thanks & Regards,

Answer (score 0):

You can view the time on logs, for example:

INFO  **17:54:06**,533 | james.mailetcontext | Mail (Mail1410537214109-a8b6d1fb-3dba-4cd6-bf05-f178dd27deb9-to-yahoo.com) sent successfully to mta5.am0.yahoodns.net. at 66.196.118.37 from hhhhhh@hhhhhh.com for [hhhhhh@yahoo.com]

Or you can change the james.mailetcontext and add other notifications.